# Does rsync support multiple sources to a given destination in parallel

Tags: linux, rsync

If I have multiple sources, each with the same directory tree, but different files in the tree, is it safe to run multiple rsync commands in parallel with the same destination?

Specifically, will there be any race conditions for directory/file creation?

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be any issues with locking or races, but I still wouldn't suggest it.

Having parts of the tree come from different hosts should work nearly as well and be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a directory is atomic so that will not cause a problem. If some of the files are the same you will probably see the last rsync that touches the file will "win".

Other than that I do not see any problems and it should be safe to do.